# Is my encoding of bitmap usable for other platforms?

Tags: java, android, base64, android-bitmap

My question is is an encoded string generated with the code below usable on another platforms and if not - how do I make it? The code is working good on android, but I am not sure what will happen if I try to expand the project.

This is the code for generating the string:

```
private String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imageEncoded;
    }
```

And this is the code for decoding it:

```
private Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        byte[] decodedByte;
        try {
            decodedByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, 0);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
```

I'm sending the string to the database and retrieving it and everything works just fine hence I can display the image. But is it usable elsewhere? And if not - how do I make it?

Comment: Define "elsewhere".  Sure, if you implemented equivalent transforms in another app ... or another programming language ... it should work.  Provided that you implement them correctly.

Comment: Lets say I get that string and try to decode it on JS or swift. Will it be okay or I have to use for example UTF-8 encoding somehow in my code?

Comment: You don't need to use UTF-8 with Base64.   Any encoding that will support a subset of the ASCII / LATIN 1 charset will do.  Digits, lowercase and uppercase letters, `+` and `/` are all that are required.  Read up on the spec for base64 encoding.  (Google it)